# Getting the error "The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist " when the MediaFoundation API ProcessMessage() returns back to the caller.

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, media, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am using VC++, VS2008. 
I get the error "The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist ".

> ProcessMessage() (IMFTransform) returns with a success status & if I
>   see the call stack, the ProcessMessage() goes inside some Microsoft
>   DLLs (like evr.dll etc...) and finally returns the error msg "The
>   owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist ".

Can anyone kindly let me know why do we get this error? And if possible how to fix it. 
Any pointers are also appreciated.  Thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

"The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist " is `0x80040207`, which is
a HRESULT code with context specific meaning, which is in this case `VFW_E_NO_ACCEPTABLE_TYPES` "There is no common media type between these pins."

See [`FACILITY_ITF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.